# Argument must implement iterable

Tags: batch, querylocator

I have the following apex batch class:

```
global class BatchUpdateListItem implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    global List<UpdateProduct> update_product {get;set;}

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        Set<String> field_names = new Set<String>();
        for (UpdateProduct o : update_product){
            for (attribute__c x : o.attributes){
            field_names.add(String.valueOf(x.field_name__c));
            }
        }

        String query = 'SELECT ' + String.join(field_names, ',') + ' FROM Product__c';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Product__c> scope){

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

    }
}
```

I am getting the following syntax error on the line where the query string is initiated (line 12):

> > Save error: Argument must implement Iterable BatchUpdateListItem.cls

I do not see this simple problem's solution, I do not want to have an iterable batch, yet a query locator one.  I do not see where it implements iterable, and therefore I do not understand where this error arises.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.join(...)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_join) expects an object which inherits the iterable interface as a first parameter, generally a list. `Set` does not implement the iterable interface, and as a result, you get this error message.

If you convert it over to a list before you call the string method, you'll be able to use your code as is.

```
String s = String.join(new List<String>(field_names), ',');
```

You can vote on an idea to change the set iterator behavior on the [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxLyAAI).